# What is the alphanumeric string in sshd log file?

Tags: ssh

In my system log, I see a line like this every time I login with SSH.  I want to know what the long alphanumeric string at the end means.  Is it safe to share this info when posting log files publicly for troubleshooting?  I have replaced it here with the same number of x characters.

```
Jun 18 21:53:50 meye-6155c1c4 auth.info sshd[1416]: Accepted publickey for admin from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 57978 ssh2: RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am using OpenSSH 7.6p1 and logging in using a public key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the **SSH fingerprint**

For eg:

> ```
> 12:f8:7e:78:61:b4:bf:e2:de:24:15:96:4e:d4:72:53
> ```

The fingerprint is used for identifying the server/machine you are connecting to, it is based on the server's Public key.

And yes it is safe to share it, as it is based on public key which is available to all

**Explanation:**

Fingerprints are unique way of identifying the host you are connecting to, they are a simple representation of **Host key**

**Host keys** are normally generated automatically when **OpenSSH** is first installed or when the computer is first booted. 
Host keys are usually stored in the `/etc/ssh directory`, in files starting with `ssh_host_<rsa/dsa/ecdsa/ed25519>_key`

You can check the **host** key fingerprint :

```
$ sudo ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
2048 SHA256:qEx0sZHQnkl5lOWN7y0geX6e1Y9lxGocluDvHtMgeOM root@197nodnb20354 (RSA)
```

If the fingerprint changes, the machine you are connecting to has changed their public key (happens from re-installing ssh), but it could also indicate that you are connecting to a different machine at the same domain/IP or that you are being targeted with a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: The hash is of a user's key, not a host key.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for terms like "SSH fingerprint" or "OpenSSH" or "public key". If you want to provide emphasis, use italics or bold. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/270345

Comment: @muru thanks for the suggestion, edited my answer and question edits

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for pointing that out, edited my answer to include the suggestion